# how to parse json object into select box.. My response is not like array format? So tel me a way to do selectbox?

Tags: json

how to parse json object into select box?My response is not like array format?

My response is

```
{"select:"<option value=apple>apple<\/option><option value=mango>mango<\/option>"}
```

I tried,

```
$('#listProduct option').html('');
$('#listProduct option').html(selectobj.select);
```

This will fetch all data into single option on select box.But i want to get drop down select box.

Tel me a way to make this into select box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to parse the json string (split at ) and add each option to the selection list:

```
var selectStr = selectobj.select;
var options = selectStr.split('</option>');

$.each(options, function (i, option) {
    $('#listProduct').append($('<option>', { 
        value: option,
        text : option 
    }));
});
```

Comment: And i want to pass id value for that option is there is a way to do that?

Comment: where do you get the id from? or is it just a counter? than use `value: i` instead of `value: option`

Comment: ya.. i will try this way to put id.. Thanks.